# What is the best method of storage for condiments?

Tags: storage-lifetime, refrigerator, condiments, ketchup

I have read a fair few articles about storing condiments like Siracha, Ketchup, and BBQ Sause, but they all seem to contradict themselves; some say that storing them in a fridge is bad since it has preservatives and other says it is bad to store at room temperature.

So, just wondering if anyone has advice on storing condiments preferably with reasoning since I am confused about how I should be taking care of them. *(Though any help is appreciated!)*

Comment: I've never heard it said that storing condiments in the refrigerator is "bad". The presence of preservatives might make it unnecessary, but I don't see how it could be harmful. Could you provide a reference to that suggestion?

Comment: Preservatives only extend shelf life by a certain time, once opened refrigeration will extend their life significantly. I can't see why you would not want to refrigerate a condiment.

Comment: GdG limited fridge space ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To a certain extent, it depends on the condiment.

For things like oil or vinegar, where germs generally can't really survive anyway, there is no need for refrigeration. On the other hand, things like ketchup, mayonnaise, or any other emulsions (tahini for instance) should be kept in the fridge.
It also depends on whether the pack is sealed or has come into contact with air already. For example, sealed packs of mayonnaise can be kept at room temperature, though an open jar must be refrigerated.

Aside from that, it's always a good idea to keep things in sealed containers, and away from direct sunlight.